# The -cp option to the java command

Tags: command, options

```
java -cp FILE.jar FILE.Main inputfile
```

What does the `-cp` option mean? For that matter, what a negative sign in front mean? I've searched everywhere and couldn't find the answer.

Comment: There is no `-cp` command. Where did you see this? Copy-paste the whole line, at least, or whatever is necessary to how the context.

Comment: java -cp FILE.jar FILE.Main inputfile

Comment: Then it isn't a command, it's an option to the `java` command.

Comment: Try `java -h 2>&1| grep cp`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example you finally gave, -cp is a parameter to the command, which is java.  Parameters are generally program-specific, in this case cp stands for Class Path, which is another location java will search to find the class files as they are needed by the program.

Answer (score 5):

See this:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Quote:

> -classpath classpath
> -cp classpath
>
> Specifies a list of directories, JAR files, and ZIP archives to search for class files. Separate class path entries with
> semicolons (;). Specifying -classpath or -cp overrides any setting of
> the CLASSPATH environment variable.